# Get list of all loaded python packages & versions, and variables

Tags: python

I'm coming from an R background where it was quite easy to figure out for me all of the loaded packages that I was using.  I could look to my rstudio tab 'packages' and see checkmarks next to package names and versions for what I had loaded / available.

I could run:

```
library(dplyr)
x=3;
y=4;
```

then run to find out the packages I had loaded('dplyr):
 `sessionInfo()`
and to find out which variables were in my environment if I didn't want to look at the loaded variable pain (x, y)

```
ls()
```

I'm trying to figure out a way to do this in python.  For example, is there a command that will:

1. Show me everything available python package I can import & corresponding versions?
2. Show me the packages I have already loaded thus far in my session and their corresponding versions?
3. Show me all my defined variables that I have made and their type (such as pandas data frames, lists, dictionaries, functions, etc)

I'm sure this is pretty easy, but I can't seem to find how to do this coming from R where it was very simple.

Comment: One question per question, please.

Comment: @jwodder, I think these questions are quite related, so it wouldn't be an improvement if this would be three or more separate questions... YMMV :-)

Comment: [help is here](http://xahlee.info/python/standard_modules.html)

Answer (score 1):

> Show me everything available python package I can import & corresponding versions?

`help('modules')`

NB: You can also type `pip freeze` on the command line to see which third-party modules you have installed using `pip`. (Use `python -m pip freeze` if you have multiple Python versions and want to be sure you list the packages for the same version as `python`.) However, this list is not complete, since it does not contain built-in modules and your own modules.

> Show me the packages I have already loaded thus far in my session and their corresponding versions?

I don't think this is possible, but see next question:

> Show me all my defined variables that I have made and their type (such as pandas data frames, lists, dictionaries, functions, etc)

`globals()`

This also includes all loaded modules. You could filter out the 'modules' if you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the currently loaded modules with [sys.modules](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.modules). This means you can use the following code to print the currently loaded modules and their versions:

```
import sys

for module in sys.modules.values():
    if hasattr(module, "__version__"):
        print(module.__name__, module.__version__)
    else:
        print(module.__name__)
```

Modules aren't obliged to provide a `__version__` attribute, so you have to check whether it exists before you use it. Most modules in the standard library don't provide a version, although interestingly, some provide versions that are different from the current version of Python.

A caveat is that you can use [importlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html) to load modules without adding them to sys.modules, so there is no guarantee that sys.modules will be accurate 100% of the time.

Answer (score 1):

For 2, you can use the session_info package (previously sinfo.sinfo()):

```
import session_info
session_info.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

**1. Not possible** in general. Import statements are handled dynamically at the time the line is executed, and so the result depends on whatever is lying around on your filesystem at that time.

You can get a decent idea of what's available by looking in the site-packages dir, the location of which is platform dependent but can be found with the code snippet below:

```
>>> import sysconfig
>>> sysconfig.get_path("purelib")
'/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages'
```

The standard library is always available. A comprehensive list of stdlib modules is in the library docs here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/

There is a helper function in [`pkgutil.walk_packages()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pkgutil.html#pkgutil.walk_packages) which will essentially walks the sys path and looks for accessible modules.  I believe pydoc's [`help("modules")`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56402654/674039) listed in the other answer actually uses this helper internally.

`pip freeze` will show distributions installed in a virtual environment.

**2. Just look in [`sys.modules`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.modules)**. A version number for a module is not required, and might not even exist, but a common convention is for the top-level module to have a `__version__` attribute.

**3. This is built-in function [`vars`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars).** Just call `vars()` with no arguments, it will return a mapping of names and objects. The types of the objects you will just have to see with `type(obj)`.

Comment: In some distributions of Python, not everything in the standard library is available by default. For example, the system Python in Ubuntu doesn't have tkinter and a few other things.

Comment: Good answer. But `pip freeze` does not only work for virtual environments. When executed in a "normal" (non-virtual) environment it'll work on the "normal" (system) environment.

Comment: No hate but I would be very cautious to say "impossible" or "not possible".

Comment: @PanwenWang Yes, I am cautious to use it. In this case it _is_ impossible in the general case, for example there is a [TOC/TOU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-check_to_time-of-use) issue here: .py files can be added or removed in between when you check what's there and when the import statement is itself executed. So there is no 100% reliable way to get a list of importable modules.

Comment: @wim Agreed. Checking something in memory can only be happening if something is loaded into memory.